# Delete class with atomic boolean from vector

Tags: c++, stdatomic

I have a vector of my class transaction and try to delete a certain range of elements using following code. When compiling I get the error:
"error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic_bool& std::atomic_bool::operator=(const std::atomic_bool&)" 
What is the right way to delete a class with an atomic boolean member?

```
void Transactions::forget(size_t up_to)
{
   size_t deletion_limit = up_to - forgotten_;
   transactions_.erase(transactions_.begin(),transactions_.begin()+deletion_limit)
   forgotten_ += up_to; 
}
```

where transactions is a vector of my class Transaction

```
class Transaction {
public:
    Transaction(std::vector<Insert> &&insert_ops, std::vector<Remove> &&remove_ops);
    void process_inserts();
    void process_removes(Database &database);
    bool inserts_processed();
    bool removes_processed();
    Affected get_affected_inserts(Relation relation);
    Affected get_affected_deletes(Relation relation);
private:
    // Clear after being processed
    std::vector<Insert> *insert_ops_;
    std::vector<Remove> *remove_ops_;
    std::atomic_bool inserts_done_, removes_done_;
    std::map<Relation, Affected> inserted_tuples_, removed_tuples_;
};
```

Comment: How about making your class movable but not copyable (i.e. delete copy constructor and copy assignment op, add move constructor and move assignment) Alternatively take charge of copying. The error message says it all about why you can't just use defaulted copying or moving: a `standard_atomic<bool>` wants just a `bool` value.

Comment: Atomic variables are not movable. Just like mutexes.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The error message says it all about why he can't just use defaulted copying or moving: a standard_atomic<bool> wants just a bool value. One aternative is to take charge of copying. But better, he should make the class movable but not copyable (i.e. delete copy constructor and copy assignment op, add move constructor and move assignment).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It's unlikely that you *want* to copy an object that contains an atomic variable. The whole point of atomic variables is to serve as synchronization points, and that requires everyone to know where the variable is. A copy of such a variable, created at some random point in time, doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @KerrekSB: A movable transaction can use a dynamically allocated internal state (that doesn't move). That reduces the assumptions here from one of no other threads accessing any transactions objects, to no other threads accessing the transaction objects to be deleted. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you provide me further information, where something like this is described